# How to mathematically get the previous and next number of a clock from 1-12 and 12-1?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algorithms, modular-arithmetic

How can I get the next and previous number of a clock mathematically?

For example:

Next hour

- input 1 → output 2
- input 2 → output 3
- input 3 → output 4
- input 4 → output 5
- input 12 → output 1

Previous hour

- input 1 → output 12
- input 2 → output 1
- input 3 → output 2
- input 4 → output 3

Thank you so much in advance

Comment: what functions are you able to use?

Comment: no if it should be arithmetic please

Comment: What on earth are you asking?  You get to the next hour by adding one and you get to the previous hour by subtracting one.  When you go past 12 you return to 1.  You must know the answer because you described it perfectly.  So what are you asking?  Are you asking how to describe it mathematically?  Are you asking how to program a computer to do it?  are you asking if we have terminology for this?

Comment: @fleablood I just edited the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h$ be the current hour. I assume you want a way to do this as a one-line function in something like a programming context, without using such things as `if h = 12 then ...`.

To get the next hour, take $h$ modulo $12$, then add $1$.

To get the previous hour, take $(h+10)$ modulo $12$, then add $1$.

Comment: yes! how do you know I wanted a one-line function?

Comment: Well, you could just use `if h = 12 then return 1 else return h+1`.

Comment: yes, the if is so obvious.

Answer (score 4):

You asked for a solution using arithmetic. Let $h$ be the current hour. Then the next hour is

$$f(h)=−\frac{h^{11}}{3326400}+\frac{h^{10}}{50400}−\frac{h^9}{1728}+\frac{11h^8}{1120}−\frac{10831h^7}{100800}+\frac{1903h^6}{2400}−\\\frac{242537h^5}{60480}+\frac{139381h^4}{10080}−\frac{341747h^3}{10800}+\frac{190553h^2}{4200}−\frac{81401h}{2310}+13$$

Comment: Lagrange's interpolating polynomial!

Comment: sorry for using different terminologies. I mean mathematically.

Comment: Well done. Next you know someone will have borrowed your polynomial to calculate $1 + h \bmod 12$ in production code ;-)

Comment: @bbn Theophile is making a joke.  You are under the common but naive (but reasonable and common) conception that the is a universal set of arithmetic symbols is we are able to use them but *only* them to express everything.  In actuality if any concept is valid we can define it ourselves.  So actually in asking your question you actually *answered* it.  The next hour is ... the next hour after 12 is 1 and the next hour after everything else is the next hour... *IS* perfectly good and valid mathematics.

Comment: how did you learn how to do this?

Comment: @bbnn Here is a [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial) on how to do this. The expression above is the interpolating polynomial that passes through the points $(1,2),(2,3),(3,4),\ldots,(12,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

0)  $next = current + 1 - 12\lfloor \frac{current}{12}\rfloor$. (because $\lfloor \frac{current}{12}\rfloor = 0$ if $current \ne 12$.)

$previous = current - 1 + (12 - 12\lceil \frac{current - 1}{12} \rceil) = current + 11 - 12\lceil \frac{current - 1}{12} \rceil$. (because $\lceil \frac{current - 1}{12} \rceil = 1$ if $current \ne 1$.)

But

1) There's nothing wrong mathematically with using an if clause in mathemetic.

$next= current+1; h < 12$

$next = 1; current = 12$

2) If you want terminology mathematics does have the concept of modulo arithmetic where $a \equiv b \mod N$ means $a = b \pm kN$ for some integer $k$.

So $next = current + 1 \mod 12$

There are two things two watch out about.  i) Theoretically $\mod N$ is not a specific designator $a = 36 \mod 15$ doesn't actually mean $a = 6$.  It means $a = 6 \pm 15k = 36 \pm 15j$ for some integers $j$ and $k$ (whatever $k$ is $j = k + 2$) but we don't know which value.  It's a description not an identification.

But some people do mean it to designate a specific value $0... N-1$ so $(36 \mod 15) = 6;  (23 \mod 22) = 1; (12 \mod 12) = 0$.  This can be a bone of contention but meaning can be clear in context but:

ii)  $12 \mod 12$ is usually interpreted as $0$ and not $12$

So you can do $next = (current \mod 12) + 1$.  [If $current \ne 12$ then $(current \mod 12) = current$; if $current = 12$ then $current \mod 12 = 0$.]

Subraction's a bit harder.  $prev = (current - 2 \mod 12) + 1$.  [If $current > 1$ then $current- 2\mod 12 + 1 = current -2 + 1 = current - 1$.  If $current = 1$ then $(current - 2) \mod 12 +1 = (-1 \mod 12) + 1 = 11 + 1 = 12$.]

But I think the 2) is ambiguous.  (I prefer 1)).

Comment: thank you for your answer. So in conclusion,  `next = h mod 12 + 1` and `prev = (h + 10) mod 12 + 1` is fine?

Comment: Yes, but to be honest, I don't think it is any better or worse than what you wrote: Next hour

    input 1 → output 2
    input 2 → output 3
    input 3 → output 4
    input 4 → output 5
    input 12 → output 1

Previous hour

    input 1 → output 12
    input 2 → output 1
    input 3 → output 2
    input 4 → output 3.  That *is* just fine.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, any better or worse that what I wrote?

Comment: I mean that what you wrote was fine and every bit as mathematical and correct as any answer anyone else has come up with.